# Individual contact type select is missing in custom field group setting

Tags: drupal, custom-fields, contact-types

When I look in CiviCRM 4.6.8 at the custom field group settings associated with organization contact, then I see a select box where I can choose the type of organization type (as defined in Customize data and screens >> Contact types).

When I compare that with the custom field group setting associated with an individual, then I don't see this select box and I can therefore not restrict the field group to a custom individual contact type.

Is this to be considered by design or is this a bug being fixed in 4.6.9? To me it seems at least inconsistent. Please note that I have both custom individual and organization contact types defined.

Comment: Hi - just out of curiosity, are you able to replicate this on the Civi demo site?  I tested creating a custom data set and was able to see the available contact subtypes for both individual and organization contact types.

Comment: Well I just discovered that I could not reproduce this in the demo. 

I'm still using 4.6.8. recently upgraded from 4.6.4. I will try an upgrade to 4.6.9, may be that helps.

Comment: 4.6.9 is available as demo but is not released yet for download. 

Meanwhile, are there any hints how to debug this problem? I would hate to redefine my prototype scheme all over again.

Answer (score 2):

I now understand why the individual subtype select was not appearing. It was simply because one of the fields was being used. The As soon as you fill in one of the custom fields of a field group then the option to change type and sub-type is removed.

I was misled by a cosmetic bug that it does not display the sub-type "any" when beside the default "individual" there were added subtypes afterwards. I will try to reproduce and report this, to prevent that others are misled by this.